# How can I get a history like query on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, logging, history

I'd like a little help here.

I'm building a database in MySQL where I will have a bunch of different activities. Each activity is part of a list.

So, I have the following tables on my database.

List

- id
- name

Activity

- id
- name
- idList (FK to List)

I also want to know when each activity is finished (you can finish the same activity many times). To accomplish that, I have another table:

History

- date
- idActivity (FK to activity)

When the user finishes an activity, I add the id of this activity and the current time the activity was finished, to the History table.

I want to get the entire list with the date it was finished. When an activity has not been finished, I want it to show the date as null.

But, getting the list just once is easy. A simple Left Outer Join will do the trick. My issue here is that I want to get the ENTIRE list everytime a date appears on the history table.

This is what I'm looking for:

List:

```
id      |       name
1       |       list1
```

Activity:

```
id      |       name        |       idList
1       |     Activity1     |         1
2       |     Activity2     |         1
3       |     Activity3     |         1
4       |     Activity4     |         1
5       |     Activity5     |         1
6       |     Activity6     |         1
```

History:

```
date      |    idActivity       
17/07/14  |        1
17/07/14  |        3
17/07/14  |        4
17/07/14  |        6

16/07/14  |        2
16/07/14  |        3
16/07/14  |        5
```

Expected Result:

```
idActivity     |     idList     |      activityName      |        date           
    1          |        1       |       Activity1        |      17/07/14
    2          |        1       |       Activity2        |        NULL
    3          |        1       |       Activity3        |      17/07/14
    4          |        1       |       Activity4        |      17/07/14
    5          |        1       |       Activity5        |        NULL
    6          |        1       |       Activity6        |      17/07/14

    1          |        1       |       Activity1        |        NULL
    2          |        1       |       Activity2        |      16/07/14
    3          |        1       |       Activity3        |      16/07/14
    4          |        1       |       Activity4        |        NULL
    5          |        1       |       Activity5        |      16/07/14
    6          |        1       |       Activity6        |        NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "trick" is to use a CROSS JOIN (or semi-cross join) operation with a distinct list of dates from the `history` table, to produce the set of rows you want to return.

Then a `LEFT JOIN` (outer join) to the `history` table to find the matching history rows.

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.id             AS idActivity
     , a.idList         AS idList
     , a.name           AS activityName
     , h.date           AS `date`
  FROM activity a
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT s.date
           FROM history s
         GROUP BY s.date
       ) r
  LEFT
  JOIN history h
    ON h.idActivity = a.id
   AND h.date = r.date
 ORDER 
    BY r.date
     , a.id
```

That query gets the six rows from `activity`, and two rows (distinct values of `date`) from `history` (inline view aliased as **`r`**). The CROSS JOIN operation matches each of the six rows with each of the two rows, to produce a Cartesian product of 12 rows.

To get the rows returned in the specified order, we order by `date`, and then by `activity.id`.